# What is the correct way of enabling 300mbps on a cisco 3502i?

Tags: cisco

OK...

I have a Cisco 3502i (AIR-CAP3502I-A-K9) radio in autonomous mode with ap3g1-k9w7-xx.153-3.JF5 firmware and I have been trying to get the 5.8 GHz radio to switch over to 300 Mbps support. So far I only show 54 Mbps (in fact this is on both radios).

What do I need to do to get this configured through the GUI to get this to support 300 Mbps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from a friend who configures Cisco products on a regular basis, he sent me this configuration script;

Do this from either a telnet or SSH login after you `en` of course:

```
conf t

interface Dot11Radio0
 no ip address
 !
 encryption mode ciphers aes-ccm
 !
 ssid {Your Radio SSID}
 !
 antenna gain 0
 speed  basic-11.0 6.0 9.0 12.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0 m0. m1. m2. m3. m4. m5. m6. m7. m8. m9. m10. m11. m12. m13. m14. m15.
 channel {Your Broadcast Frequency}
 station-role root
 no dot11 extension aironet
 bridge-group 1
 bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
 bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning
 no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding
!
end
```

and then do `wri mem` and you should be good to go.

If there are any errors, well, then something went wrong. But the above script DEFINITELY worked for me.