# How do I enable or bond the 80MHz channels on a Cisco 3502i AP in autonomous mode?

Tags: cisco, command-line-interface

I have a Cisco AIR-CAP3502I-A-K9 using F/W ap3g1-k9w7-xx-153-3.JF5 in autonomous mode. I have tried everything I can think of (Google has NOT been my friend) to configure the 5GHz radio to use 300MBps? I can get the additional channels configured using this CLI command:

> speed  6.0 9.0 12.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0 m0. m1. m2. m3. m4. m5. m6. m7. m8. m9. m10. m11. m12. m13. m14. m15.

But the most I get on a speed test is about 27 Mbps using an iPhone 7 plus with only 2 clients connected to the AP.

I have also followed the following Serverfault page with no luck either - YES, this is a post I posted, and at the time, it "appeared" to work, but NOT really:
[What is the correct way of enabling 300Mbps on a Cisco 3502i?](https://serverfault.com/questions/911994/what-is-the-correct-way-of-enabling-300mbps-on-a-cisco-3502i#)

So what am I missing?

My AP configuration with masked fields follows.

```
!
! Last configuration change at 17:59:43 -0700 Sun Jun 9 2019 by Cisco
! NVRAM config last updated at 17:59:47 -0700 Sun Jun 9 2019 by Cisco
! NVRAM config last updated at 17:59:47 -0700 Sun Jun 9 2019 by Cisco
version 15.3
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
hostname ap
!
!
logging rate-limit console 9
enable secret XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
!
no aaa new-model
clock timezone -0700 -7 0
no ip source-route
no ip cef
ip domain name XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
!
!
!
!
dot11 pause-time 100
dot11 syslog
!
dot11 ssid 4ff0-58
   authentication open 
   authentication key-management wpa version 2
   guest-mode
   infrastructure-ssid
   wpa-psk ascii XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
!
dot11 ssid 7ab0-24
   authentication open 
   authentication key-management wpa version 2
   guest-mode
   infrastructure-ssid
   wpa-psk ascii XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
!
!
!
no ipv6 cef
!
!
username Cisco password XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
!
!
bridge irb
!
!
!
interface Dot11Radio0
 no ip address
 !
 encryption mode ciphers aes-ccm 
 !
 ssid XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 !
 antenna gain 0
 speed  basic-11.0 6.0 9.0 12.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0 m0. m1. m2. m3. m4. m5. m6. m7. m8. m9. m10. m11. m12. m13. m14. m15.
 channel 2462
 station-role root
 no dot11 extension aironet
 world-mode dot11d country-code US indoor
 bridge-group 1
 bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
 bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning
 no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding
!
interface Dot11Radio1
 no ip address
 !
 encryption mode ciphers aes-ccm 
 !
 ssid XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 !
 antenna gain 0
 peakdetect
 dfs band 3 block
 speed  basic-6.0 9.0 12.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0 m0. m1. m2. m3. m4. m5. m6. m7. m8. m9. m10. m11. m12. m13. m14. m15.
 channel width 40-above
 channel 5180
 station-role root
 no dot11 extension aironet
 world-mode dot11d country-code US indoor
 bridge-group 1
 bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
 bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning
 no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding
!
interface GigabitEthernet0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 bridge-group 1
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning
!
interface BVI1
 mac-address 70ca.9b98.f5bf
 ip address dhcp client-id GigabitEthernet0
 ipv6 address dhcp
 ipv6 address autoconfig
!
ip forward-protocol nd
ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip http help-path http://www.cisco.com/warp/public/779/smbiz/prodconfig/help/eag
!
!
bridge 1 route ip
!
!
!
line con 0
line vty 0 4
 login local
 transport input all
!
sntp server 132.163.96.1
sntp broadcast client
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> interface Dot11Radio1
> channel width 40-above

You have the 5GHz radio configured for 40MHz channel width.

The actual speed you get from a speed test will be far different than the wireless PHY speed.